# Word(s) describing the sound of wet snow flakes (slowly) falling on snow?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word accurately describing the *sound of wet snow flakes* (slowly) *falling on snow*? Here is an [*audio sample*](https://www.freesound.org/people/pcaeldries/sounds/86262/) of a variation thereof(sound system warning: start with low gain or use headphones). Note this doesn't exhibit the same properties as [*sleet*](https://www.freesound.org/people/pcaeldries/sounds/89488/) or small ice pellets falling, which is dryer and shorter a sound. I'm trying to make a sentence such as *I'm listening to the ...ing sound of the snow falling*... An adjective would also work.

Comment: It's pretty quiet. I think using 'quiet' would work. Or 'silence of the falling snow'. Or ''.

Comment: What about a "hard-whispering-liquid laughter?"

Comment: As a casual reader, I simply enjoyed reading the description...
*I'm listening to the sound of wet snow flakes falling slowly on snow* It is very vivid

Comment: "Wet" snow flake: http://www.theweatherprediction.com/habyhints/232/

Comment: _Wet_ is surely quite idiomatic in itself... I can see the "value". Thanks all!

Comment: "I'm listening to the ...ing sound of the snow falling" Now now, there's no need for that! I actually rather like snow!

Comment: Perhaps there is no sound at all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the audio sample, a few words jump to mind:

> [pattering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patter)

This is often used with raindrops, especially the slow sound of rain on the rooftop.  You might also try *pitter-pattering*.

> crunching

I'm not sure if it's just the audio sample, but it sounds very crunchy to me.

> crackling

See my thoughts on *crunching* above.  Also, like Rice Crispies:  snap, crackle, pop.

> settle

"...the sound of the snow as it settles on the ground."

Comment: +1 The clip sounds very similar to the crackling of wood on a fire.

Comment: Thank you! I'll select this answer for its focus on descriptive terms relating to the beat of the snow, _crackling_ and something hinting at alternation i.e. pitter-pattering. What I found also insightful by contrast is how the _wet_ property is little rendered in the As; the idea of voice is used i.e. whisper etc. Going into this I had crackling/smooching in mind plus cliquetis/clapotis(fr, the former can be render the "metallic" noise of armor softly - one answer alludes to tinkling for instance - the latter has that watery element which has been little rendered here overall).

Answer (score 7):

I listened to the audio clip and was quite surprised... hearing that without the context I never would have guessed it was snow.

Still, if you are game for personification, then I have three suggestions:

> I'm listening to the **whispering** sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the **murmur** of falling snow.
>
> I'm listening to the **sigh** of falling snow.

These three words evoke the quietude implied in the very act of listening to the snow fall.

Comment: When I was 14 I wrote some verse that spoke of the *whispering wetness falling. . . .*  It isn’t worth presenting, but it stands that I think *whisper* good for this.

Comment: I very much like murmuring for this. "I stand by the window, listening to the soft murmuring of the snow as it falls" ...

Answer (score 6):

How about "[susurration](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/susurration)" or, better yet, "susurrus"?

> Susurration: a soft, whispering or rustling sound; a murmur.
>   Susurrus: a soft murmuring or rustling sound; whisper. - TFD

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Brandon. Your post would be improved if it included a reference, and explained the merits of your suggestion.

Comment: +1 - great word, evocative... I wonder if it was onomatopoetic in the original Latin.

Answer (score 2):

The late lamented Harry Harrison coined a phrase for this in *[Bill, the Galactic Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill,_the_Galactic_Hero)*, in a rousing chorus sung by the deplanned (those who have lost their street plans):-

> Stand together One and All
>
> For Brothers Deplanned always shall
>
> Unite and Fight to achieve the Right
>
> That Might shall fail and Truth avail
>
> So that we
>
> who once were free
>
> can someday be
>
> Once more free to see the skies of blue Above
>
> And hear the gentle pitty-pat
>
> Of snow.

Comment: The NED has it at [_pit-a-pat_](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/910/mode/2up): _echoic, expressing alternating sounds; an imitation of the repeated or alternating sound made by a strong beating or palpitation of the heart in excitement or emotion; also of that of light or rapid footsteps, or of similar or alternating or reiterated sounds_. Nice find! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think [crackling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crackling) best describes the noise from  the audio sample:

> - short, dry, sharp sounds made by something:
>
>   - We could hear the crackling of a fire.

or [tinkling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tinkling):

> - light metallic sounds, as those of a small bell.

( from TFD)

Comment: Someone already used crackling.  Tinkling makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - we posted the answer together..anyway it is so nice to hear from you Rye..from time to time!:))

Answer (score 0):

The title implies that more than one word may be acceptable... If so, I'd be tempted to go for crackling (as suggested already) but with a modifier in front that suggests the lighter snow qualities.

How about either:

Gentle crackling

Ethereal crackling

The former is more ordinary. The latter may not be to all tastes, but seems to me more in line with the delicate nature of the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'll contribute quiet [*smooching/smouching*](https://archive.org/stream/oed9aarch#page/n299/mode/2up)(kissing), [*lapping*](https://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/68/mode/2up)(tongue in water), [*plashing*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/954/mode/2up)(strike the surface of water) and [*swashing/swashy*](https://archive.org/stream/oed9barch#page/n299/mode/2up)(sloppy, watery). Organic undertones clash a bit with the scene whereas the water effects lack a bit in terms of showing off the [*slushy*](https://archive.org/stream/oed9aarch#page/250/mode/2up) element.

Comment: How about:"*The "soft slush" sounds of falling snow*"? The OED in your link has *slush-slush* and *slushy splashy* too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you, that could work too! But somehow, fire and water may be antinomic in the descriptive sense. Or an arbitrary choice is made to focus on the impact sound of the flake as opposed other properties; or such other properties are assimilated to voice. It seems in a way nothing beats _wet_ which is very idiomatic in context. Most of the answers I provide contain those s/sh sounds; I'm not a native speaker, I'm concerned these sound like a "snake" lol or wind. It is all interesting, especially this pragmatic focus on the idiomatical constructs. Ty.

Comment: Snake-like sounds would contain the suffix -iss, typically *hissing*, or perhaps *swishing*, as in "a snake swishes its tail".

Answer (score 0):

Abstractive words:

- Diffusing.
- Effusing. Spreading out loosely.
- Affusing.

Explanative words:

- Scattering.
- Sploshing. Scattering liquid.
- Dispersing. Vanish or disappear.
- Dissipating.
- Frittering. The sound of boiling oil.
- Dissolving.

Positive emotions may increase the atmosphere also:

- Amusing.
- Pleasing.
- Arousing.
- Satisfying.

It's possible to increase the value of ..ing word for example:

> I'm listening to the *constant* ...ing sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the *deep* ...ing sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the *endless* ...ing sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the *perpetual* ...ing sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the *incessant* ...ing sound of the snow falling.
>
> I'm listening to the *continuous* ...ing sound of the snow falling.

Answer (score 0):

*The hush of falling snow* captures it for me.

Answer (score -1):

What about a "gentle-harsh-whispering-liquid laughter?"  This is not just a single adjective, as requested, but it gives the "feel" of what you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the OP request for a single word or a word ending in *-ing*. It doesn't seem nice, either, Unless you fly into an auditory-irritant-induced fit of adjective slinging whenever snow falls gently in your presence.